# Is it possible to have more than one remote Mac open in Remote Desktop at a time?

Tags: remote-desktop

Is it possible to have more than one remote Mac open in [Apple's Remote Desktop software](http://www.apple.com/uk/remotedesktop/) at a time ?

Some tasks take a while on some computers so I'd like to be able to dip in and out of multiple machines whilst its working. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you have to select the machines one at a time and click the "control" button.

Comment: You can have a window-full of observed machines. I've never tested it [cos I don't have enough machines here] but can you observe, then swap to control on a new machine, then another... all from that window  ?

Comment: From my, admittedly very limited experience, it works similarly to Microsoft RDP. Each window is a separate remote connection and you don't swap the contents of one window (Mac #1) for another (Mac #2) you swap the window itself. Simple and easy though.